# Angular ui router state : same template for multiple states , not using parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to use same template url and controller for different states/url in my application.

Eg : mypage.com & mypage.com/event have same template url.

```
.state("index", {
 url: "/",
 template: 'EVENTS',
 controller:eventscontroller
 })


.state("events", {
 url: "/events",
 template: 'EVENTS',
 controller:eventscontroller
 })
```

Is it possible with ui router. Please help

Comment: This is possible but would you want to use the same controller for different urls?

Comment: yes , can we do like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like this:

```
 $state.state('main.a',{
      url: '/a',
      templateUrl: 'templates/tpl.html',
      controller:'AController',
      }
  });

 $state.state('main.b',{
      url: '/b',
      templateUrl: 'templates/tpl.html',
      controller:'AController',
      }
  });
```

But I am not sure why would you like for a controller to serve 2 routes?